# By default, will autohandler be triggered when requesting an image file (Mason)?

Tags: perl, mod-perl, mason

By default when I'm requesting an image file - will the mason handler trigger `autohandler`? Only `.html` files are set to be handled by mason in the config file. I need it to happen to do some background tasks but I don't want the image file itself to be processed. Please advice...

**Update**, I'm going to experiment with the following in `autohandler`:

```
return -1 if $r->content_type && $r->content_type !~ m|^text/|i;
```

And with the following in `apache2.conf`:

```
<FilesMatch "(.*)>
```

Comment: so, are you palnning to pass to mod_perl all the request?  and it could help if you'll say more about your deployment infrastructure: 1 ApacheMP? proxy + ApacheMP? etc.

Comment: And info about software verions will be helpful as well. I also don't recommend to return numerical values, `mod_perl` has predefined constants for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try using LocationMatch:

```
<LocationMatch "\.(css|html)$">
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlHandler ...# it depends on your current configuration
</LocationMatch>
```

Also you say you don't want to process an image, put those image files in another directory and let the default-handler serve it:

```
<Location /images>
    sethandler default-handler
</Location>
```